# How can we use ternary operator with as many else-if as we want?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

The basic ternary operator usage is

```
(condition) ? True part : False part
```

How can we add "multiple-else-if" functionality to that?

Comment: Nested ternary operator can be used accordingly.

Comment: Please adopt a less noisy formatting style. For questions and answers.

Comment: @Yunnosch new to stackoverflow...sorry

Comment: How do you use nested termary operations? *Answer:* Very Sparingly -- if at all. Combining multiple ternary operations in one leads to unreadable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(condition 1)? True statements for cond. 1 :(condition 2)?  True statements for cond. 2: else statements
```

We can use conditional operator to add else if condition in one line.

Example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
     for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
          printf("%d%s\n",i,(i==1)?"st":(i==2)?"nd":(i==3)?"rd":"th");
}
```

Result

```
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
10th
```

Answer (score 3):

When chaining the ternary operator, formatting is key to making it readable:

Trying to do it all on one long line makes it unintelligible.

```
int result = (oper=='+')?  a+b : 
             (oper=='-')?  a-b : 
             (oper=='/')?  a/b : 
             (oper=='*')?  a*b : 
             (oper=='^')?  a^b : 
             (oper=='&')?  a&b : 
             0;
```

Or, to format Zafeer's example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
     for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
          printf("%d%s\n",i, (i==1)? "st":
                             (i==2)? "nd":
                             (i==3)? "rd": 
                                     "th");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The grammar says pretty clearly how you can do it. The grammar is:

```
conditional_expression
    : logical_or_expression
    | logical_or_expression '?' expression ':' conditional_expression
    ;
```

https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

That says that whatever comes after `:` should be a valid *conditional_expression*.

But this is rarely a good thing to do. According to the answer you gave, you want to use it to format printouts. But it would be much better to extract it to a separate function, like this:

```
const char* suffix(int n)
{
    static const char suffix[][3] = { "st", "nd", "rd", "th" };
    int rIndex;
    /* Some logic */
    return suffix[rIndex];
}
```

And then

```
printf("%d%s\n", i, suffix(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as flow control is concerned , the ternary works just like `if-else`, and nests just like `if-else`

SIMPLE

```
if (cond ) yes ; else no;
~
(cond) ? yes : else no
```

LADDER

```
if (cond ) yes ;
else if (cond2) cond2yes;
else  if (cond3) cond3yes;
else cond3no;
~
cond  ? yes :
cond2 ? cond2yes :
cond3 ? cond3yes :
cond3no
```

Recently I needed a bunch of complex nested ternaries and I found
structuring them like this to be most easily readable, especially
with the help of a parenthesis-matching editor:

```
cond ? (
    yes
) : ( cond2 ? (
        cond2yes
    ) : ( cond3 ? (
            cond3yes
        ) : (
            cond3no
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You consider the last shown  code to be more readable than the ladder, aka the answer by abelenky?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes. I used to do it abelenky-style, but I find I orient myself faster in the last one. You can sort of read the it like standardly formatted `if-else` ladders. The `?` lines say `if(/*...*/) {`, the `) : ( /*..*/ ?`  is `}else if(/*...*/){`. The `) : (` is `} else {`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I find the abelenky style more readable for simple logic, but I think the parens help if your expressions are complex.

Comment: I feel differently, but I accept your view. Maybe I differ because my favorite way of using ternaries is NOT (courtesy DCR).

Comment: @Yunnosch That I can mostly agree on. But sometimes you have little choice. E.g., if you want a macro that expands to an integer constant expression for constant inputs.